# Computing centroid of blob with OpenCV gives incorrect result

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have some C++ code to compute the centroid of a blob, where the inputted image consists of a single object (the blob) and a small amount of background noise. However, my code it not giving me the result that I expect. I have tested this on many different images, and the resulting centroid position always appears to be biased towards the left and upwards of the blob.

Here are the general steps in my implementation:

1.) **Decimation**: The original image buffer is decimated by a factor of `decimation` using `cv::pyrDown()`.

2.) **Binary Thresholding**: The decimated image is thresholded using OpenCV's
function, `threshold()`, with the `cv::THRESH_BINARY` option. The threshold is calculated as the mean pixel intensity plus some small offset determined by `thresh_offset`.

3.) **Grouping**: Connected component analysis is then performed on the resulting binary image. `cv::connectedComponentsWithStats()` is used to determine all pixel groups having at least 4 degrees of connectivity.

4.) **Determine the Blob Group**: Conveniently, the first group detected by `cv::connectedComponentsWithStat()` is the background. It can be discarded. Then, groups containing an extreme and negligible number of pixels can also be discarded. These values are determined by `extreme_size_thresh` and `min_size_thresh`, respectively. Of the remaining groups, the largest group is the blob. This will serve as the ROI for the next steps.

5.) **Windowing the ROI**: A window is formed around the blob group in the original image (i.e., in the image before decimation and thresholding). A border of a few pixels pads the ROI. This is determined by `border_size`.

6.) **Thresholding the ROI**: Once again, the threshold is computed from the mean pixel intensity of the pixels in the ROI plus some small offset. However, instead of binary thresholding, all pixels below the threshold are set to 0 and all pixels above the threshold remain their original value. This is done using OpenCV's `threshold()` function with the `cv::THRESH_TOZERO` option.

7.) **Computing the Centroid**: The centroid of the remaining pixels in the window is computed by applying the standard center of mass formula. Then, the centroid is resized such that is corresponds to the pixel position in the original image. The algorithm concludes by returning the `x` and `y` coordinates of the centroid position.

In my setup, I have three files: `centroiding.cpp`, `centroiding.h`, and `main.cpp`. Here is the code for each file:

**centroiding.cpp**:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "centroiding.h"

double *find_centroid(uint8_t *image_array, uint32_t SizeY, uint32_t SizeX, double thresh_offset, int extreme_size_thresh, int min_size_thresh, int decimation, int border_size)
{
        double max_value = 255.0;    /* Maximum pixel value for binary thresholding.  */
        int e;
        int r;
        
        /* Convert image arrays into cv:Mat objects. */
        cv::Mat image(SizeY, SizeX, CV_8U, image_array);

        /* Decimate image array */
        cv::Mat decimated_image = image.clone();
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < (decimation / 2); i++)
        {
                cv::pyrDown(decimated_image, decimated_image);
        }
        
        /* Compute binary image by binary thresholding. */
        cv::Scalar decimated_mean_pixel_intensity = cv::mean(decimated_image);
        double decimated_thresh_val = decimated_mean_pixel_intensity[0] + thresh_offset;
        //std::cout << "Threshold value: " << decimated_thresh_val << std::endl;

        cv::Mat binary;
        threshold(decimated_image, binary, decimated_thresh_val, max_value, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

        /* Connected component analysis on resulting binary image. */
        cv::Mat labels, stats, centroids;

        int num_components = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(binary, labels, stats, centroids, 4, CV_32S);

        /* Determine the group sizes. The first group is the background. It is discarded. */
        std::vector<int> group_sizes;

        for (i=1; i<num_components; i++)
        {
                group_sizes.push_back(stats.at<int>(i, cv::CC_STAT_AREA));
        }

        /* Find the largest of the remaining groups. This is the blob. */
        int max_group_size = 0;
        int group_index;
        for (i=1; i<num_components; i++)
        {
                int members = stats.at<int>(i, cv::CC_STAT_AREA);
                if (members > max_group_size)
                {
                         max_group_size = members;
                         group_index = i;
                }
        }
        //std::cout << "Most significant group size: " << max_group_size << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "Group index: " << group_index << std::endl;

        /* Form a window around the largest group in the original image. */
        double window_thresh_offset = 15.0;

        int x_min_decimated = stats.at<int>(group_index, cv::CC_STAT_LEFT);
        int y_min_decimated = stats.at<int>(group_index, cv::CC_STAT_TOP);
        int x_max_decimated = x_min_decimated + stats.at<int>(group_index, cv::CC_STAT_WIDTH);
        int y_max_decimated = y_min_decimated + stats.at<int>(group_index, cv::CC_STAT_HEIGHT);

        int x_min = x_min_decimated * decimation - border_size;
        int y_min = y_min_decimated * decimation - border_size;
        int x_max = x_max_decimated * decimation + border_size;
        int y_max = y_max_decimated * decimation + border_size;

        cv::Rect window(x_min, y_min, x_max - x_min, y_max - y_min);

        /* Threshold the window. */
        cv::Scalar window_mean_pixel_intensity = cv::mean(image(window));
        double window_thresh_val = window_mean_pixel_intensity[0] + window_thresh_offset;
        //std::cout << "Window threshold value: " << window_thresh_val << std::endl;

        cv::Mat thresholded_window;
        threshold(image(window), thresholded_window, window_thresh_val, max_value, cv::THRESH_TOZERO);

         /* Compute the centroid of this window. */
         double sum_x = 0;
         double sum_y = 0;
         double *windowed_centroid = new double[2];
         for (e=0; e<thresholded_window.rows; e++)
         {
                 for (r=0; r<thresholded_window.cols; r++)
                 {
                          double intensity = thresholded_window.at<double>(e, r);
                          double sum_x = sum_x + intensity * r;
                          double sum_y = sum_y + intensity * e;
                  }
          }
          windowed_centroid[1] = sum_x / max_group_size;
          windowed_centroid[0] = sum_y / max_group_size;

          /* Resize the centroid such that it corresponds to the centroid in the original image. */
          
          double *real_centroid = new double[2];
          real_centroid[0] = windowed_centroid[0] + x_min;
          real_centroid[1] = windowed_centroid[1] + y_min;

          std::cout << "Centroid: " << "(" << real_centroid[0] << ", " << real_centroid[1] << ")" << std::endl;

          delete [] windowed_centroid;

          return real_centroid;
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "centroiding.h"

int main()
{
        /* Parameters for find_centroid() */
        double thresh_offset = 15.0;
        int extreme_size_thresh = 20000;
        int min_size_thresh = 1;
        int decimation = 4;
        int border_size = 2;

        /* Run the image through centroiding algorithm */
        std::string data_directory = "/home/aknighton/test_data";

        /* Get image file name */
        std::string file_name = data_directory + "/test_image.png";

        /* Load image file */
        cv::Mat image = cv::imread(file_name, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

        /* Check to see if image was loaded successfully */
        if (image.empty())
        {
                std::cerr << "Could not open or find image " << file_name << std::endl;
    
        }
        /* find_centroid() expects an image array as input, so we must access the image array from the cv::Mat object */
        uint32_t SizeY = image.rows;
        uint32_t SizeX = image.cols;

        uint8_t *image_array = image.data;

        /* Allocate memory for centroid */
        double *centroid = new double[1 * 2];

        /* Pass to find_centroid() */
        std::cout << "Computing centroid..." << std::endl;
        centroid = find_centroid(image_array, SizeY, SizeX, thresh_offset, extreme_size_thresh, min_size_thresh, decimation, border_size);
          
        delete [] centroid;
}
```

**centroiding.h**:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

EXTERNC double *find_centroid(uint8_t *image_array, uint32_t SizeY, uint32_t SizeX, double thresh_offset, int extreme_size_thresh, int min_size_thresh, int decimation, int border_size);

#undef EXTERNC
```

I wrote `centroiding.h` like this because in my application I actually need to call `find_centroid()` from a C main function.

To use this code the only thing you should have to change is the path to the test image in `main.cpp`. Here is how I built the executable `compute_centroid` (assuming that all three files are in the same directory):

```
g++ -Wall -pthread -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -c centroiding.cpp

g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -c main.cpp

g++ main.o centroiding.o -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_video -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_flann -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lstdc++ -o compute_centroid
```

I am going to attach a test image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsLF8.png) that you can use. If you run this sample through the code, you should get that the centroid is `(1658, 1702)`, where 1658 is the column position and 1702 is the row position. However, I *know* that the exact centroid is actually `(1714, 1755)`, because I generated this image synthetically. The intensity of the blob is Gaussian and the mean for the blob in that image is at that position. Hence, I would expect the computed centroid to be very close to that position, but it appears to be to the left and upwards of that position. In fact, that appears to be the case for *every* centroid that gets computed. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TNJ5.png) image. The white objects are the actual blobs and the red points are the computed centroids. There seems to be a constant bias... Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: Did you look at all intermediate images to verify they look like you expect? I would suspect that something goes wrong with the cropping or the translation of coordinates.

Comment: The code you have posted in fails in compilation. There are syntax errors, and also ` error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'sum_x' used` and `warning C4456: declaration of 'sum_x' hides previous local declaration`. Consider posting all the code as a single cpp file.  Think how to simplify the code before posting - you suppose to post a minimal reproducible code sample.

Comment: @Rotem I just found, and fixed, two syntax errors. The first one was in `centroiding.cpp`. I was missing a minus sign between `x_max` and `x_min` when passing to `cv::Rect()`. The other was in `main.cpp`. I was missing a semicolon at the end of the `data_directory` line. With those two edits, the code posted in the question compiles fine on my end... I did not encounter those other two errors.

Comment: Error or not, it's still a bug... When writing: `double sum_x = sum_x + intensity * r;`, `sum_x` is declared and used in the same line. I think you just meant: `sum_x = sum_x + intensity * r;`, because `double sum_x = 0;` is above the loop. (same for `sum_y`). Fixing the errors was not a problem for me. The "minimal reproducible code sample" part is more important.